# How to pass variable to mysql together with the single quote

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing an angular apps with php as backend.

I have angular service that will pass the parameter to the php to to the query to mysql database.

However i am a bit confused on how to pass the parameter together with the single quote.

**function**

```
var Matcode = $scope.add.matcode.matcode;

SelectDistinct.getListinct('min_in_body','location',"matcode='Matcode'").success(function(data){
    $scope.Locations = data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  }).error(function(){
    $scope.Location = null;
    console.log("failed");
  }).finally(function() {
    console.log("success");
  });
```

the third param in `getListinct` is the condition which i need to provide to the mysql, in this case i will provide where `matcode=` var `Matcode` as i have declared above.

The problem is that the function will pass something like `SELECT location FROM min_in_body WHERE matcode='Matcode'` instead the content of the var `Matcode` itself. so how do i workaround for this issue?

Comment: Are you passing sql commands via HTTP requests to you backend? From your code it looks like this, but I can't tell for sue. If yes, give this a good read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection .

Comment: yes, i am passing some mysql conditions via HTTP post. Thanks for the article, great for newbee like me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var Matcode = $scope.add.matcode.matcode;

SelectDistinct.getListinct('min_in_body','location',"matcode='" + Matcode + "'")
```